# Qemu Guest Cannot Access HTTP Nginx from Host

Tags: linux, iptables, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I installed nginx in Host to share Http to guest Qemu KVM but when I open in browser using IP Address 192.168.122.1 it's failed cannot load my web apps

I thought it was iptables or forwarding issue

Here's my iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And here's my firewall-cmd --list-all :

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s25 wlp3s0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp 1433/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Anything wrong here?

I tried open 192.168.1.2 my local in virtualbox it's works fine
but failed in Qemu/KVM

But when I ping the IP address only 192.168.122.1 and 192.168.1.2 it's fine

Comment: Something has gone very wrong with your firewall rules. Start over by restarting firewalld then restarting libvirtd. Then show the output of `iptables -S`.

Comment: i dont See any nat rules, is that so planned?

Comment: the problem is when i'm running it using Virtual Manager, I set NIC virtual network default NAT, maybe should change it or add other NIC, But when I Run directly from terminal qemu with parameter `-net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::60022-:22` it's works fine